# Need an Explanation for the Correct Final Answer

Tags: vectors, physics

I was solving the problem below and my answer was 56 degrees but, in the answer key, it was 180-56=124 degrees as the final answer. Can someone explain why 56 was subtracted from 180? Apologies if my question seems too simple.
[image]

Comment: Look at the sign of $-6.00$.  The angle must be more than $90^\circ$

Comment: **HInt**: Try to analyze in which quadrant sine function is positive but cosine function is negative.

Comment: These helped me understand, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\theta$ be the angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$. Then :
$$\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B} = \|\vec{A}\|\|\vec{B}\| \cos(\theta) = -6$$
and :
$$\|\vec{A} \times \vec{B}\| = \|\vec{A}\|\|\vec{B}\|\ |\!\sin(\theta)| = 9.$$
This yields :
$$\frac{|\!\sin(\theta)|}{\cos(\theta)} = -\frac{3}{2}.$$
The angle $\theta$ then has to be in the second or third quadrant for the cosine to be negative. There are two solutions now, either $180° - \arctan(-3/2)$ or $180° - \arctan(3/2)$, depending on the sign of $\sin(\theta)$.